# Driveway sinking

Tags: driveway, asphalt

I have a paved driveway that seems to need repair or replacing. There are some cracks throughout, but near the bottom there are spider cracks. I noticed the other day after some rain that it felt loose and gave a little when walking over this part. None of the pieces are loose to the point that they can be removed, but water was coming out of them when stepped on. 
The rest of the driveway seems structurally sound, with minimal cracking.
Can this be patched?

Comment: I, personally, would be afraid that you have a sinkhole problem.

Comment: That might be jumping the gun a bit going from 'cracks' to 'sinkhole'.

Comment: you can patch it, but given what you said, it sounds like the problem is the base--not the slab itself. If that's the case, then a patch will eventually crack too.